# Why does wobble board makes a howling sound?

Tags: waves, acoustics

I noticed that when bending a large plate it makes a howling sound. However, having made a number of experiments I found that if we bend the plate from the initial position, we will not hear the sound. But if we first bend it a little and turn it sharply to the other side, we will hear this howling sound. With the help of a piezosounder I found that the frequency of the plate vibrations coincides with the frequency of the sound we hear. But I never understood why the phenomenon is not observed if you just bend the plate to one side.

Answer (score 1):

The wobbling creates vibrations, which we hear as sound. Infact, these can change depending on the material which is usually plywood or plastic (easy to vibrate). Faster wobbles also create higher pitched noises and slower wobbles it's counterpart!